# Removing duplicates on subset of columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table which is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
 [1,]    1    5   10 0.00040803 0.00255277
 [2,]    1   11    3 0.01765470 0.01584580
 [3,]    1    6    2 0.15514850 0.15509000
 [4,]    1    8   14 0.02100531 0.02572320
 [5,]    1    9    4 0.04748648 0.00843252
 [6,]    2    5   10 0.00040760 0.06782680
 [7,]    2   11    3 0.01765480 0.01584580
 [8,]    2    6    2 0.15514810 0.15509000
 [9,]    2    8   14 0.02100491 0.02572320
[10,]    2    9    4 0.04748608 0.00843252
[11,]    3    5   10 0.00040760 0.06782680
[12,]    3   11    3 0.01765480 0.01584580
[13,]    3    8   14 0.02100391 0.02572320
[14,]    3    9    4 0.04748508 0.00843252
[15,]    4    5   10 0.00040760 0.06782680
[16,]    4   11    3 0.01765480 0.01584580
[17,]    4    8   14 0.02100391 0.02572320
[18,]    4    9    4 0.04748508 0.00843252
[19,]    5    8   14 0.02100391 0.02572320
[20,]    5    9    4 0.04748508 0.00843252
```

I want to remove duplicates from this table. However, only colums 2,3,4 matter. Example: rows 1,6,11,15 are identical if only columns 2,3,4 are observed. Note for column 4: is it possible to incorporate that it is considered as being the same as long as it is within 10e-5 of the value? So that rows 1 and 6 would be considered as being identical although the value in column 4 differs slightly (within the tolerance I mentioned)?

Then it would be great to get an output which would be like:

```
column 2 value | column 3 value | column 1 value at which the the pair has been first observed (with the tolerance) (in the example 1) | column 1 value at which the pair has been last observed (with tolerance) (in the example 4) | value of column 4 at first appearance (0.00040803 in the example)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of thinking about it, but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for.  The logic should be able to get you started though.

```
dat <- YOUR DATA SET
dat
   V1 V2 V3         V4         V5
1   1  5 10 0.00040803 0.00255277
2   1 11  3 0.01765470 0.01584580
3   1  6  2 0.15514850 0.15509000
4   1  8 14 0.02100531 0.02572320
5   1  9  4 0.04748648 0.00843252
# TRUNCATED

dat <- dat[, c(2, 3, 4)]
dat$V4 <- round(dat$V4, 5)

unique(dat)
  V2 V3      V4
1  5 10 0.00041
2 11  3 0.01765
3  6  2 0.15515
4  8 14 0.02101
5  9  4 0.04749
9  8 14 0.02100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
# read your data
yy <- read.csv('your-data.csv', header=F)

##   V1 V2 V3         V4         V5
## 1  1  5 10 0.00040803 0.00255277
## 2  1 11  3 0.01765470 0.01584580
## 3  1  6  2 0.15514850 0.15509000
## 4  1  8 14 0.02100531 0.02572320

# create a logical matrix indicating value is within tolerance
mat.eq.tol <- sapply(yy$V4, function(x) abs(yy$V4-x) < 1E-5)
# minimum index
eq.min <- apply(mat.eq.tol, 1, function(x) min(which(x)))
# maximum index
eq.max <- apply(mat.eq.tol, 1, function(x) max(which(x)))

# combine result
res <- cbind(yy$V2, yy$V3, yy$V1[eq.min], yy$V1[eq.max], yy$V4[eq.min])

##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]       [,5]
## [1,]    5   10    1    4 0.00040803
## [2,]   11    3    1    4 0.01765470
## [3,]    6    2    1    2 0.15514850
## [4,]    8   14    1    5 0.02100531
## [5,]    9    4    1    5 0.04748648
## [6,]    5   10    1    4 0.00040803
```

Comment: what would happen in your code if row 1,6 and 11 would be identical (whcih they are) but then lines 15 and 19 would be identical so both would have column2 5 column3 10 but then in column 4 another value than 1,6 and 11 (like 0.5). The output would than need to be: 5/10/1/3 (for 1 to 3) and then 5/10 4 to 5